# Timer dispatching changes out of order on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, timer, begininvoke, dispatch

I'm trying to make a countdown timer on Windows Phone 7, which is really important for my application. But I can't find any method to update text in UI regullary every one second.

```
Timer dt = new System.Threading.Timer(delegate
{
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
      newtime = oldtime--;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("#" + counter.ToString() + 
                                         " new: " + newtime.ToString() + 
                                         " old: " + oldtime.ToString());
      counter++;
      oldtime = newtime;
   }
}, null, 0, 1000);
```

After running my app console output seems like this:

> ```
> #1 new: 445 old: 446
> #2 new: 444 old: 445
> #3 new: 445 old: 446
> #4 new: 443 old: 444
> #5 new: 444 old: 445
> #6 new: 442 old: 443
> #7 new: 443 old: 444
> #8 new: 441 old: 442
> ```

I can't figure out how to get rid of that unwanted invokes (#3, #5, #7, etc.)

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You don't show where those variables are declared, but I assume outside the method itself, which means the anonymous method you pass to the timer captures them, and now you've got unsynchronized reads and writes to shared memory using the non-threadsafe decrement operator. Also, instead of using a threading timer and dispatching, just use a dispatcher timer, whose tick event will be raised on the dispatcher thread itself, obviating the need for an invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead. The following example shows a timer doing a countdown from ten.

```
DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
int _timeLeft = 10;

public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    _timer.Start();
    MyTextBox.Text = _timeLeft.ToString();
}

void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timeLeft--;
    if (_timeLeft == 0)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        MyTextBox.Text = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MyTextBox.Text = _timeLeft.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, looks very good but when running DispatcherTimer, numbers go down by 2..  

`7/16/2012 3:56:17 PM >> 567
7/16/2012 3:56:18 PM >> 566
7/16/2012 3:56:18 PM >> 565
7/16/2012 3:56:20 PM >> 564
7/16/2012 3:56:20 PM >> 563
7/16/2012 3:56:21 PM >> 562
7/16/2012 3:56:21 PM >> 561`

Comment: I have this same code in an app and it works fine. Make sure that _timeLeft is only getting decremented on the one line within TimerTick, also that the Interval for _timer is set to one second

Comment: I'm sure that this variable is decremented only once in my code.. But it seems like DispatcherTimer raises tick more than one in second, even when set trough TimeSpan.. Don't know why. When I run my app for long time and watch the countdown, most of time it goes down by 2 but sometimes for a few moments it goes down nicely one after one... That's why I've tried to use Timer instead of DispatcherTimer in my solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following mod:

```
DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200) };
int _timeLeft = 50;
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
_timer.Tick += TimerTick;
_timer.Start();
textBlock1.Text = _timeLeft.ToString();
watch.Start();
}
void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((_timeLeft - (int)watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) <= 0)
    {
        watch.Stop();
        _timer.Stop();
        textBlock1.Text = null;
    }
    else
    {
        textBlock1.Text = (_timeLeft - (int)watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    }
}
```

By the way Shawn's code just works fine on my device but if you're experiencing problems, just use a `Stopwatch` and subtract the elapsed time from your time variable. Also, run `DispatcherTimer` a little faster (of course for this technique) like 200ms for greater accuracy (everything has been implemented above). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code and at the comments, I suspect that the fault with your application is not with the Timer code, but instead with whatever initialises the Timer - I suspect the timer is being constructed twice.

It's hard to debug this without seeing the code outside of the block you've posted, but the symptoms you describe suggest that you are initialising multiple Timers and multiple stack/closure variables `oldTime` and `newTime`

At a simple level, you could try protecting the Timer construction - e.g. with something like:

```
public class MyClass
{

// existing code...

private bool _timerStarted;

private void StartTimer()
{

if (_timerStarted)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Timer already started - ignoring");
    return;
}

_timerStarted = true;

var newTime = 500;
var oldTime = 500;
var counter = 1;

Timer dt = new System.Threading.Timer(delegate
{
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
      newtime = oldtime--;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("#" + counter.ToString() + 
                                         " new: " + newtime.ToString() + 
                                         " old: " + oldtime.ToString());
      counter++;
      oldtime = newtime;
   }
}, null, 0, 1000);
}
}
```